# twilio play hold music and redirecting to dial

Tags: php, twilio

Aim: I want that when the call is created it should play music instead of ringing and noone is available to pick call . after playing music it should say it.
after that it should redirect to feedback page

Now: call is created and mp3 is played when we pick the call and feedback page is running when it is dialling the call

So I want a solution to handle this

```
<?php
  if (($nowtime >= $start_time) && ($nowtime <= $end_time)){
      $the_mnum = $con ->load_field($the_id, 'the_mnum');
      //$m= $the_mnum;
      //echo $the_mnum;
?>     <Say voice="woman"> 
        We are directing your call to the therapist.
      </Say>


<?php
      $check_therapist = true;
      $_SESSION["the_mnum"] = $the_mnum;
      break;
    }
  }

  if ($check_therapist){ 

    $version = '';
  $sid = '';
  $token = '';
  $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version); 
  $call = $client->account->calls->create("+1", $the_mnum, "wekaw1.mp3", array());
echo $call->sid;

    ?>
 <Redirect>feedback.php</Redirect>
    <?php } else {?>
    <Say voice="woman"> 
      No listener is available right now. 
      We will give you a call back shortly when we have available listener. 
    </Say>
<?php } ?>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to play hold music instead of rings before 2 numbers are connected you need to use [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) and [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue) combined and initiate a call via our Rest API.

The following is an example [implementation in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php).

You need to assign the file below to your phone number. This code will `<enqueue>` the call and initiate a call forwarding to your number. This will also initiate a request to the second file that you need to create (modify_leg.php).

In some file first.php:

```
$name = $_POST['CallSid'];

echo '<Response><Enqueue>'.$name.'</Enqueue></Response>';

// Make sure to include php-helper library
require('../Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library
$account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$auth_token = 'aaxxxxxxxxxxx';
$from_number = '+1xxxxxx';
$to_number = '+1xxxxxxxx';
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
$message = $client->account->calls->create($from_number, $to_number, 'http://Your-FQDN/modify_leg.php?callSid='.$name);
```

Now in [(modify_leg.php)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) you will pass `$_GET[callSid]` so it will actually connect both calls once you answer the phone and the caller will listen to music until you actually pick up the call.

```
<?php

$who = $_GET['callSid'];

?>
<Response>
<Dial><Queue><?php echo $who ?></Queue></Dial>
</Response>
```